# C#: Why does List<String>.Equals(String) compile?

Tags: c#, string, generics

In my Java days I got used to doing `.Equals()` for comparisons instead of `==` (at least for cases where I knew / had tested for whether the object I called `.Equals()` on was not null).

I just ran into a problem with some C#.NET code that had been missed for a few versions because it compiled OK, but at runtime it always returned false, but I'm a bit confused about why it compiled, can somebody please explain? (I'm guessing it maybe has something to do with `Equals()` being inherited from `object`, but didn't see a good reference for this).

**Story:** I had a class I use for filtering database queries, called `WorkFilter`, and I converted the filter engine to support multi-value filters (as opposed to just single-value filters). So each filter field property of `WorkFilter` was converted from `String` to `List<String>`, and I converted most of the code (except this one case I missed) to deal with this, and it was fine for a while until I noticed that a certain condition was never `true`.

Filter class looks like this:

```
public class WorkFilter
{
    public List<String> RecordType { get; set; }
    public List<String> Product { get; set; }
    ... etc ...
}
```

The "bad" code was doing this:

```
if (workFilterInstance.RecordType != null && workFilterInstance.RecordType.Equals("REQUEST"))
{
    // code that never gets fired because List<String> never equals String value
}
```

I fixed it to do this (basically):

```
if(workFilterInstance.RecordType != null && workFilterInstance.RecordType.Contains("REQUEST"))
{
    // now this can handle logic for RecordType = "REQUEST" filters
}
```

I was kicking myself because I know that if I had used `==` instead, it would have failed at compile time, for example, if I did this: `RecordType == "REQUEST"` because you can't use the equality operator to compare `List<String>` and `String`.

But I was surprised by my misunderstanding of `.Equals()` because I expected `RecordType.Equals(String)` to also generate a compiler error (or at least a runtime error, instead of always returning `false`)... I mean, why would you ever compare `List<>` to `String` anyway, and why did this compile?

I poked around MSDN a bit but was hoping somebody could explain it in plain english. Thanks!

Comment: Because `List<T>` is an `Object` and `Object` provides `Equals` implementation.

Comment: But why would that not throw an exception at runtime?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary What kind of protection do you need? it will return false. Isn't it not enough. (or use `==` to get an compile time error)

Comment: Why *would* it fail? It would just return false, since an object of type string cannot equal an object of type List<string>.

Comment: For what it's worth, ReSharper catches this and gives a `Suspicious Comparison` warning, and offers to remove the comparison altogether.

Comment: @L.B Good "protection" would be a warning when doing this without needing Resharper. However, I don't expect to do this kind of change often. I suppose it's not worth arguing that if comparing two different class instances using `Equals()` will never return true, then why even bother with the comparison, and why not throw an exception (since [obviously?] unintended). In this case it was just my failure to do a 'find all references' when refactoring. I may have to post a followup question: why would you ever use .Equals() to compare objects of different types? (polymorphism maybe?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `List<T>` is an `Object` and Object provides [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation. Which is defined as:

```
public virtual bool Equals(
    Object obj
)
```

now since your parameter passed is a `string` which is again an object, it compiles.

For your comment:

> But why would that not fail at runtime? Is there no protection against
>   doing what I did? –

It will return false. There is no reason for it to fail. *(Although IMO, it should show a warning)*. If you use Resharper you will get a warning:

> Suspicious comparison: there is no type in the solution which is
>   inherited from both

Comment: Thank you for the tip about resharper and for the good explanation

Answer (score 6):

This code compiles because the `Equals` method of `List<T>` is an override of the `Equals` method of [`System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public virtual bool Equals(
    Object obj
)
```

It would not fail at runtime because the contract for `Equals` requires that

```
x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).
```

and `System.String`'s `Equals(Object)` [will return `false` if it is passed something that is not a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkfd9eh8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `true` if obj is a String and its value is the same as this instance; otherwise, `false`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, to be fair you answered first but I found Habib's answer a bit more in tune with my level of knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it would be nicer if you would get a warning or error for that.

However, the type system is not rich enough to express that.
You want to write

```
public virtual bool Equals(??? o);
```

Where `???` means any type convertible to the qualifier on which the method was called.

It should be fairly easy to write a Roslyn diagnostic to catch this.

Comment: Yeah I would settle for a warning. I have to google "Roslyn diagnostic" now. :)